# Python - classification and sequence matcher of scores

Tags: python, machine-learning, pattern-matching, match, classification

I'm writing a program in Python in which, based on a given dataset of scores (ie. person 1 has scores in different tests of 3,15,6,7,4,3 and is therefore a type C), compares a new set of scores for person n and determines the type (A-C) for this person. For the classification I was thinking of going down the machine learning route but I'd also like to determine the person ID which is the closest match to person n and which is the least similar (the scores are very unlikely to be the same, I need to find the closest). I was thinking of using the Levenshtein Python C extension or SequenceMatcher, does anyone have any suggestions or advice on how I could go about both the classification and the matching please?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, don't think the tests are sequences. Are the tests in a particular order and the order is important in answering your question?

Assuming they are not ordered or order is not important, you can treat each test as a dimension in a vector space, for example:

```
            test1   test2   test3   class
person1       3       0       1       A
person2       5       7       9       C
```

For the classification problem, you can try supervised learning models such as linear regression or random forest.

For finding the nearest neighbor, just compute the cosine similarity between each pair of persons.  The score `1 - similarity` can be used to find the most distant person.  Alternatives to cosine similarity include Euclidean distance.

Here is simple Python code for computing cosine similarity:

```
def dot(v1, v2):
    return sum([x1*x2 for x1, x2 in zip(v1, v2)])

p1 = [3, 0, 1]
p2 = [5, 7, 9]
cosine = dot(p1, p2) / ((dot(p1, p1) ** 0.5) * (dot(p2, p2) ** 0.5))
```

Comment: Great, thank you. Implemented your suggestions and seem to work well.